# Android: How to trigger an event on a visibility change on a View?

Tags: java, android

In order to avoid lag and the bug in which a portion of a previous layout is still showing, I want to only set the visibility of a View to visible only when the previous layout is no longer visible. How do I attach a listener to see if the previous layout is no longer visible?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `onVisibilityChanged` ?

```
protected void onVisibilityChanged (View changedView, 
                int visibility)
```

> Called when the visibility of the view or an ancestor of the view has changed.

Documentation link:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onVisibilityChanged(android.view.View,%20int)